# How is Big Table of Google App Engine Datastore designed?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

Ok, Google App Engine got a function so called "**Datastore**".
We got the following table from Google datastore website:

```
Concept                         Datastore            Relational database
Category of object              Kind                 Table
One object                      Entity               Row
Individual data for an object   Property             Field
Unique ID for an object         Key                  Primary key
```

OK, let say we got the following code:

```
DatastoreService ds=DatastoreServiceFactory.getDatastoreService();
Entity e1=new Entity("Person1");
e1.setProperty("First Name", "Tom");
e1.setProperty("Last Name", "Mary");
ds.put(e1);

Entity e2=new Entity("Person2");
e2.setProperty("First Name", "Brat");
e2.setProperty("Last Name", "Pit");
ds.put(e2);
```

My question is that:

What will happen in Google Big Table after the above code runs?

Will it create an entry like the following in Big Table?:

```
Person1 {First Name: Tom}; {Last Name: Mary}
Person2 {First Name: Brat}; {Last Name: Pit}
```

Is Big Table like a big `Text file (.txt)` or something like that? & when data got inserted into Big Table, then it just comes like 1 new entry in that big table?

OK, now look at the "**MyProject\war\WEB-INF\appengine-generated\local_db.bin**", I can see this picture
[image]

As you can see the way app engine stores data is very weird

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you see in local_db.bin file does not reflect the way the Datastore works. This is a file that is used to `emulate` Datastore - it's impossible (and unnecessary) to recreate on your computer the way the "real" Datastore works.

The real Datastore is not a giant text file. You can think of it as a giant HashMap.